# Redirect to a route without the assigned base path in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a vue router implemented and the configuration looks something like this:

```
  const router = new Router({
      mode: "history",
      base: '/base/path,
      routes,
    });
```

Then my routes looks something like:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/products",
    name: "products",
    component: () => import("#/test/items/Index.vue"),
    beforeEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
      if (//SOME CONDITION THAT SHOULD MATCH){
              next('url/without/base'); // ROUTE THAT SHOULD BE WITHOUT BASE
    }
    next()
  },
},

]
```

in the above case scenario whenever the `IF` condition is fullfiled the router is redirected to `localhost:8080/base/path/url/without/base`.
Is there a way or option so that the specific route is loaded without the base path so it would look something like: `localhost:8080/url/without/base`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a direct option for this but it sounds like something you will need to use `window.location` rather than `next()` to redirect to since that route will fall outside of your router's routes definition.

You could probably accomplish this by stripping the base url from `router.START_LOCATION` (Vue Router v3.5.0+), something like this:

```
beforeEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
  if (//SOME CONDITION THAT SHOULD MATCH) {
    const url = `${router.START_LOCATION.replace(router.base, '')}/url/without/base`;
    window.location.replace(url);
    return;
  }
  next();
}
```